# How can I access a production Mongo DB database on modulus with meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, modulus.io

I have the URI of the modulus database, but I don't know how to connect to it through meteor mongo.  What command can I use?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to connect to an external Mongo database with Meteor is to use an environment variable when starting Meteor:

```
$ export MONGO_URL="mongodb://user:password@address.com/dbname"
$ meteor run
```

The syntax for the mongo connection string is

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>/<database>?<options>
```

When hosting with modulus they have a dedicated page where you can set environment variables.

Comment: when running `meteor meteor run` I get `'meteor' is not a Meteor command. See 'meteor --help'.`, what does the `export` do? doesn't seem to do anything after. How do I get to mongo console if the database is in modulus?

Comment: There was a `meteor` too much - removed it in my answer