# How to update the mongodb 2.4.9 that comes with meteor to 2.6 latest

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am wondering how to update it to 2.6, because my project needs a few of 2.6's features. I know some people have done it but I can't find out how to.
edit: To clarify I mean update it so I am running mongodb 2.6+ when I run meteor on `http://localhost:3000/` for developing my project.

Comment: You can set up your MongoDB instance normally and then set your `MONGO_URL` environment variable. See [in the docs, Deploying -> Running on your own infrastructure](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying).

Comment: @sbking I edited the question to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with the `meteor` command line tool. You will have to install Mongo 2.6 yourself (can be on any machine, local or remote), then connect the local meteor instance to it. See the answer I gave here: [How can I access a production Mongo DB database on modulus with meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026264/how-can-i-access-a-production-mongo-db-database-on-modulus-with-meteor/27034434#27034434)

Imagine you install MongoDB from homebrew, you start the database and connect meteor like that:

```
$ export MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor"
$ meteor meteor run
```

You need to set up a `meteor` database manually.